# Unable to display the value of a variable in batch file

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

I have a batch file to count the number of specific files in a folder. The contents are given below:

```
set xx = %DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
set count=dir C:\Archive\*%xx%.csv | find "File(s)"
echo %count%
```

But the output of the last command displays as

```
echo
ECHO is on
```

What am I doing wrong here?? Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a command an retrieve its output you need the `for /f` command (see `for /?` help)

```
set "xx=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%"
for /f %%a in ('dir /a-d /b "c:\Archive\*%xx%.csv" ^| find /c /v ""') do set "count=%%a"
echo %count%
```

This will execute a dir command for the required files without folders included in the list, in bare format (no header, summary and no aditional file info) and instead of search for the `File(s)` (in a different windows locale the text is different), it uses `find` to count (`/c`) the number of non empty lines (`/v ""`). The output is a number that is stored in the `for` replaceable parameter `%%a`, and then copied to the required variable

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked on windows 7. But when I tried the same on windows server, it throws an error like 'find' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: @user1407668, `find.exe` is a standard element from MS-DOS times. Try to replace the call to `find` with `find.exe` or `"%systemroot%\system32\find.exe"` just in case the path is not correctly set